# Laravel Many To Many Merges Pivot?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, relationship

I must be going insane or be really tired. So I have this situation where I get a collection of all the Roles assigned to the User. That part goes ok.... however I noticed something super strange.

I am using Laravel 8 and PHP8 (not the strange part).

For some reason, I do not get only the result from the other table but also pivot data is merged in. I can't tell why this is happening. Here is the example:

Relationship on user model:

```
   /**
     * Relationship with roles model.
     *
     * @return BelongsToMany
     */
    public function roles(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            Role::class,
            'role_user',
            'user_id',
            'role_id'
        )->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Relationship on the Role model:

```
/**
 * Relationship with users table.
 *
 * @return BelongsToMany
 */
public function users(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        User::class,
        'role_user',
        'role_id',
        'user_id'
    )->withTimestamps();
}
```

In the user model, I have this.

```
$this->roles->each(function($role) {
    dd($role);
});
```

I was expecting to get a dump of related model however for some weird reason what I get is pivot table merged with the model:

```
"id" => 7 // this is the relation ID from the pivot table
"display_name" => "Administrator" // this is from Role model
"code" => "admin" // role model
"description" => "Super User - can do everything in the system. This role should only be assigned to IT staff member." // role model
"created_at" => "2021-10-01 11:00:00" // pivot table
"updated_at" => null // pivot table
"deleted_at" => null // pivot table
"role_id" => 1 // pivot table
"user_id" => 2 // pivot table
```

Either I am doing something very wrong or I am missing something very obvious. Does anyone know what in the world is happening here?

Just to add: the data is from both places but the result is just a Role model as expected.

Should I not just get the role model without the pivot stuff in it? It is overriding my role model fields.

**EDIT:**

Parenthesis seems to make a difference. The data is still merged. However, when I do it like this looks like data from end model is merged (so it overrides) to data from the pivot. So I get correct ID.

```
$this->roles()->each(function($role) {
       echo $role;
   });
```

But this gives me this weird pivot merged version with wrong ID.

```
$this->roles->each(function($role) {
       echo $role;
   });
```

Comment: did you defiend $with property in User or Role Models?

Comment: @OMR I didn't. I added extra content to my post though. I am not sure what is the difference here between the two but it has something to do with how relationships work.

Comment: Could it be that I am trying to use the relationship from within the model?

Answer (score 0):

I know what that was exactly. Without thinking I've added the ID column into the pivot table.

This ID from pivot was overriding my ID from my end model. After I've removed it the problem is gone.

I don't know why Laravel would by default add these fields and merge with pivot columns... I guess it just does that for no reason. Although I don't understand what's the point if there is a separate mechanism to access the pivot table (pivot relationship on the model).

This makes me think I did something wrong. But yeah, hope it helps. If anyone knows why Laravel automatically adds pivot stuff, let me know.